Anderson 100 single hung sash is not tight in frame
Just curious if this is fixable/adjustable.
I put a couple of these replacements in and both have a loose sash from side to side. Feels like it's too small for the frame or something. When opening and closing I can grab each end by the opposite corner and tilt it side to side inside the frame 1/8" or so and is very loose. I need to apply steady even pressure to both sides when closing or opening. It sits and locks fine.
I tried taking the sash off to inspect the balance, but couldn't get it out. I'm going to try again today with more persistence! Trying to contact Anderson with no luck so far.
I've seen some reviews mention this issue too, which I unfortunately didn't see before buying.
Anderson 100 series replacement inserts
Appreciate any suggestions!

Did you spread the frame when you installed it? Aside from checking square with diagonal measurements you should put a straightedge on the sides and shim as necessary.

I just got off the phone with an Anderson rep.
I guess it's normal operation due to the way they were constructed allowing for the sash to be removed the way they are (removed from the sides). He said they don't make shims or anything for this line to address this unfortunately. Also mentioned it doesn't affect their sealing. Guess I'll know if that's true next winter as I'm in MN!
